# Scaling a form with fingers in mobile browsers in lsFusion

Tags: lsfusion

How can I disable zooming of the form with fingers in mobile browsers, so that large form buttons don't shift?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
user-scalable=no
```

doesn't work